# Angular 5 unable to set the option in drop down box

Tags: angular, ngfor

I want to retain the option in the drop down box based on the value which comes from the database. In the `.ts` file, I did the follows:

```
public availList: any = [{'id':0, 'value':'Open'}, {'id':1, 'value':'Closed'}];
```

And in the `.html`, I did the follows:

```
<select class="form-control" name="monday" id="monday" [ngModel]="user.monday" (ngModelChange)="user.monday = $event" (change)="AvailabilityChange($event.target.value, 'monday')" #monday="ngModel">
  <option *ngFor="let av of availList" [value]="availability.availability">{{av.value}}</option>
</select>
```

I saw the value of availability.availability returns 0 by doing `{{availability.availability}}` however, I see that in the drop down box, no option has been selected. it should select the option "Open".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `user.monday = 0` in your class, so "Open" will be selected on pageload.

Answer (score 0):

You creating a list of options with the same value, template should look like this:

```
<option *ngFor="let av of availList" [value]="av.id">{{av.value}}</option>
```

and value of `availability.availability` should be assigned to the select's model - `user.monday`

Comment: Thanks. But I want to pre-select the option with Open. Which option will be pre-selected, will be depend on the value of "availability.availability" as this will return 0 or 1.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand you. To pre select an option in dropbox you have to set it's model value.

Comment: Yes, I did like `[ngModel]="availability.availability"` and it works well.